# pow function blocking all threads with ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

Even though the first example about the ThreadPoolExecutor uses the pow function ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html ) it seems that using pow abnormally blocks all threads when called. See code below.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=16)

def blocking():
    i = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        i+=1
        print("block",i)
        if i>3:
            print("Starting pow....")
            break
    block= pow(363,100000000000000)
    return True

def non_blocking():
    i = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        i+=1
        print("non",i)

    return True

f1 = executor.submit(blocking)
f2 = executor.submit(non_blocking)
```

I expected the output:

```
block 1
non 1
block 2
non 2
block 3
non 3
block 4
Starting pow....
non 4
non 5
non 6
non 7
non 8
```

but the program stops running after "starting pow...." giving the result:

```
block 1
non 1
block 2
non 2
block 3
non 3
block 4
Starting pow....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your python implementation (probably CPython) must have a [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) (GIL)

`pow` is a native Python function, which doesn't release the GIL when called, efficiently blocking all executions while it's running and it's running quite a while.

If you want non-blocking, use [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) instead. A separate process means 2 separate GILs and not blocking. It has the exact same interface. It also has more constraints as it requires parameters to be *picklable* (no convenient shared memory like with threads)

Note that this computation probably never ends or ends up with "out of memory error":  since it's power between integers with a *big* power value, so it doesn't overflow like floats would do but computes and computes, creating bigger and bigger integers each time

Estimated numbers of digits for this number is roughly:

```
>>> math.log10(363)*100000000000000
255990662503611.25
```

10^14 digits that is more than any current computer can handle memory wise, and also CPU-wise.

Comment: I've posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) a while ago, and was wondering whether or not there are other native Python functions (or situations) that would behave in the same way as `pow()` does, i.e., blocking and not releasing the GIL until is complete (even if executed in a seaparate thread)? The same behaviour occurs if `pow()` is called using `asynchronous` programming, even if it is executed in an external threadpool which is `await`ed, will still block the event loop, and I guess, as you mentioned, the only solution would be to use `ProcessPool` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of Python's global interpreter lock (GIL).

If you look at the bytecode for your function:

```
import time

def blocking():
    i = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        i+=1
        print("block",i)
        if i>3:
            print("Starting pow....")
            break
    block= pow(363,100000000000000)
    return True

import dis

dis.dis(blocking)
```

which looks like this:

```
  4           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  5           4 SETUP_LOOP              50 (to 56)

  6     >>    6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (time)
              8 LOAD_METHOD              1 (sleep)
             10 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             12 CALL_METHOD              1
             14 POP_TOP

  7          16 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             20 INPLACE_ADD
             22 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  8          24 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (print)
             26 LOAD_CONST               3 ('block')
             28 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             30 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             32 POP_TOP

  9          34 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             36 LOAD_CONST               4 (3)
             38 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
             40 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        6

 10          42 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (print)
             44 LOAD_CONST               5 ('Starting pow....')
             46 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             48 POP_TOP

 11          50 BREAK_LOOP
             52 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6
             54 POP_BLOCK

 12     >>   56 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (pow)
             58 LOAD_CONST               6 (363)
             60 LOAD_CONST               7 (100000000000000)
             62 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             64 STORE_FAST               1 (block)

 13          66 LOAD_CONST               8 (True)
             68 RETURN_VALUE
```

You'll notice that the `pow` call happens at 62 as a single bytecode instruction. The GIL can only be handed off between bytecodes, so since `pow(363,100000000000000)` takes a long time to execute, the other thread doesn't get a chance to run during it.

Answer (score 0):

```
pow(363,100000000000000)
```

if a big computation. It takes times for it to process and give the result

simple computation:

```
>>> import time
>>> def test(power):
...     start = time.time()
...     pow(363, power)
...     return time.time() - start
...
>>> for power in range(1,11):
...     print(test(pow(10, power)))
...
6.198883056640625e-06
2.1457672119140625e-06
3.0517578125e-05
0.0009307861328125
0.0421295166015625
1.7541508674621582 #This is a (363, 1000000)
```

Time increases exponentially